# Milter-greylist socket always owned by root?

Tags: 14.04, server, postfix

For some reason, the socket used by `milter-greylist` is always owned by root, whilst it should be owned by the user `milter-greylist` runs at. This is all installed from the repos, under Ubuntu Server 14.04. I have configured the user to `greylist` and confirmed that the daemon runs as such. What am I missing?

**Edit:** The PID file gets the correct user, just not the socket.

My `/etc/default/milter-greylist`

```
# Defaults for milter-greylist initscript
# sourced by /etc/init.d/milter-greylist
# installed at /etc/default/milter-greylist by the maintainer scripts
# 2006-08-18 Herbert Straub

# Change to one to enable milter-greylist
# Don't forget to edit the configuration file 
# /etc/milter-greylist/greylist.conf
ENABLED=1

PIDFILE="/var/run/milter-greylist.pid"
SOCKET="/var/spool/postfix/var/run/milter-greylist/greylist.sock"
USER="greylist"

# Other options
# OPTIONS=""
```

The start of my `/etc/milter-greylist/` (the rest is unmodified)

```
#
# Simple greylisting config file using the new features
# See greylist2.conf for a more detailed list of available options
#
# $Id: greylist.conf,v 1.48 2010/04/15 07:51:29 manu Exp $
#

pidfile "/var/run/milter-greylist.pid"
dumpfile "/var/lib/milter-greylist/greylist.db" 600
dumpfreq 10m

# For sendmail use the following two lines
# socket "/var/run/milter-greylist/milter-greylist.sock"
# user "smmsp"

# For Postfix uncomment the following two lines and comment out the
# sendmail ones above.
socket "/var/spool/postfix/var/run/milter-greylist/milter-greylist.sock" 660
user "greylist"

# Log milter-greylist activity to a file
#stat ">>/var/milter-greylist/greylist.log" \
#      "%T{%Y/%m/%d %T} %d [%i] %r -> %f %S (ACL %A) %Xc %Xe %Xm %Xh\n"
# Same, sent to syslog
#stat "|logger -p local7.info" \
#      "%T{%Y/%m/%d %T} %d [%i] %r -> %f %S (ACL %A) %Xc %Xe %Xm %Xh"

# Be verbose (or use -v flag)
#verbose

# Do not tell spammer how long they have to wait
quiet

# MX peering
#peer 192.0.2.17
#peer 192.0.2.18

# Your own network, which should not suffer greylisting
list "my network" addr { 127.0.0.1/8 10.0.0.0/8 192.0.2.0/24 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a nice solution, but in the end, I resorted to setting the group sticky bit on the directory. That did the trick.